# Get schema location from XML file (noNamespaceSchemaLocation)

Tags: java, sax

We are parsing an XML file with the SAX parser. Is it possible to get the schema location from the XML?

```
<view id="..." title="..."
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="{schema}">
```

I want to retrieve the `{schema}` value from the XML. Is this possible? And how to I access this value of `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`? I'm using the default SAX Parser.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                         String name, Attributes attributes)
{ .... }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends with what kind of tool/library you are working (a basic SAXParser? Xerces? JDom? ...) But what you want is the value of the attribute "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" in the namspace defined by the URI "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

in JDom, it would be something like:

```
Element view = ...; // get the view element
String value = view.getAttributeValue("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
```

Comment: Thank you, The basic SAX Parser, I adjusted my question, but the "attributes" don't contain this value...?

Comment: Hum, I haven't used SAXParser in a while but the Attributes should contain the value you are looking for. To find the correct value, you need to find the index of the attribute, and for that, you need the QName of your attribute "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", ie, something like: "{ h t t p : / / www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation" (remove all blanks in the QName)

Comment: Thank you, the error was that it's only accessible with the namespace, so I have to use "`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`" with the leading `xsi`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I get the XSD's name using `XMLStreamReader`:

```
public static String extractXsdValueOrNull(@NonNull final InputStream xmlInput)
{
    final XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    try
    {
        final XMLStreamReader r = f.createXMLStreamReader(xmlInput);
        while (r.hasNext())
        {
            final int eventType = r.next();
            if (XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT == eventType)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= r.getAttributeCount(); i++)
                {
                    final boolean foundSchemaNameSpace = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI.equals(r.getAttributeNamespace(i));
                    final boolean foundLocationAttributeName = SCHEMA_LOCATION.equals(r.getAttributeLocalName(i));

                    if (foundSchemaNameSpace && foundLocationAttributeName)
                    {
                        return r.getAttributeValue(i);
                    }
                }
                return null; // only checked the first element
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (final XMLStreamException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Actually XMLStreamReader does all the magic, namely:

- only parses the XML's beginning (not the whole XML)
- does not assume a particular namespace alias (i.e. `xsi`)